# Dynamically generating fragments for a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am new to using a `ViewPager`, but the initial screen on my app is a `ListView` that the user can add/remove new items to, then clicking on one of the items brings them to a "details" fragment based on an id that is passed.  I'd like for the user to also be able to swipe from the listing through to each of the details.

I have the `ViewPager` working, except the id's are always off by one.  This might be my lack of understanding of `ViewPagers`, but if I put a breakpoint in the `onCreateView` of the details fragment, the breakpoint is hit when the app loads and the id that is passed is the first id.  So, say the ids are 1,2,3,4, when the app loads, the id on app start-up in `onCreateView` is 1. When I perform the initial swipe from the listing to the first details fragment, the id is 2 (when I would expect it to be 1).

This is what I have so far:

**Main.class (this initial activity on app start-up)**

```
public class Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private static int NUMBER_OF_PAGES;  
    private ViewPager mViewPager;  
    private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter; 
    private static List<Fragment> fragments;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);  
        mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);

        final List<Integer> ids = GetIds(); //loads ids to popular the viewpager

        NUMBER_OF_PAGES = ids.size();

        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        fragments.add(new ListingFragment()); //initial screen

        for(Integer id : ids)
            fragments.add(DetailsFragment.newInstance(id));
    }

    private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {            

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
             super(fm);  
        }

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {

            return fragments.get(index);
        }

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  

             return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;  
        }
   }
}
```

**DetailsFragment.class**

```
public class DetailsFragment extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private int detailId;
    private List<Integer> items;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onActivityCreated(icicle);
    }

    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int id) {

        DetailsFragment lf = new DetailsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("id", id);
        lf.setArguments(bundle);
        return lf;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);

        detailId = getArguments().getInt("id"); //this id is always off

        items = GetItems();

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the ViewPager working, except the id's are always off by one.
>   This might be my lack of understanding of ViewPagers, but if I put a
>   breakpoint in the onCreateView of the details fragment, the breakpoint
>   is hit when the app loads and the id that is passed is the first id.
>   So, say the ids are 1,2,3,4, when the app loads, the id on app
>   start-up in onCreateView is 1. When I perform the initial swipe from
>   the listing to the first details fragment, the id is 2 (when I would
>   expect it to be 1).

Maybe I don't understand the problem you're facing but the code you posted(again, if that is the full code you use(currently it will not compile as your `DetailsFragments` extends `SherlockFragmentActivity` (?!))) can't do what you say. The way you setup the fragments will make the them have the proper ids.

What you're seeing it's most likely due to the way the `ViewPager` works, which can be misleading. When you first start the app you'll see the `ListingFragment`. Now, the `ViewPager`, in order to provide a smooth swipe for the user will also load(by default) one additional fragment on each side of the current visible fragment(so when the app starts the `ViewPager` will load page `0`(`ListingFragment`) and the next(to the right as we don't have anywhere to go left)) page, `1`(the `DetailsFragment` with the id `1`). When you swipe from the `ListingFragment` to the first `DetailsFragment`(which has the id `1`) the `ViewPager` will automatically create the second `DetailsFragment`(which has the id `2`) in advance(again, in order to be able to swipe right away to it). Now, if you have a `Log` statement in the `onCreateView` in the `DetailsFragment`(to see the `id`) it's normal that you see the second id as you swipe from the `ListingFragment` to the first `DetailsFragment` because that `Log` will not appear from the first `DetailsFragment`(with id `1`, which is already created) being created, it will appear because the second `DetailsFragment`(with id `2`) is being created in advance.

Also, revise your code, as you introduced a subtle bug. You set the size of the adapter to 
`NUMBER_OF_PAGES` which is initialized with `ids.size()` but then you add the `ListingFragment` which will make the `DetailsFragment` with the last id(from `ids`) not appear at all.

Comment: you're right.  I forgot to add `ids.size()+1`.  This is a stripped down version of the code, so I added it to the question wrong.  But this is all the code that related to the `ViewPager`.  So, it's your understanding, that the above code should be working?  If it is, it must be something outside the `ViewPager` that is causing the ids to be off.

Comment: @KrisB I still don't understand, how do you see that the ids are off by 1? Do you have log statements? Is the fragment content offset with the id? Something else?

Comment: I think I'm finally getting my head wrapped around this.  I was mistaken, the id's are not off, it's just how you described it, as I'm swiping, it's executing the next id.  This sort of leads to another question.  What is the best event to place initialization code for the fragments?  In `onCreate`, `onCreateView`, `onResume` or `onActivityCreated`.  I am setting the title of the `ActionBar` as I swipe, but it looks like it's getting set too early.  For example, when I'm on the first screen, the title shown is the next screen in the `ViewPager`.

Comment: @KrisB The fragment should create its view in the `onCreateView` and other initialization in the `onActivityCreated`(but you could mix this, it's not something clearly set). If you want to set the title then set a `OnPageChangeListener` in the `ViewPager` and set the title in one of those methods. For example, you could change the title in the `onPageSelected`(this will be called when the swipe gesture to the next page finishes). Otherwise use the other methods of the interface.

Comment: The only problem with using `onPageSelected` is that I'm setting the title dynamically based on the id that is passed through `newInstance` method, which I think I can do using the `position` variable that is passed in?  However, I also need to set the title in `onActivityCreated` of the details in case the user selects on item from the initial screen's `ListView`, instead of swiping.  Is there an event that is only fired when the user selects on item and not swipes though?  BTW, thanks for your responses, they are big help, as it seems the `ViewPager` documentation is kind of lacking.

Comment: @KrisB Well, you have the list of ids, `GetIds()`(which I'm assuming don't change) and the `position` from `onPageSelected` so you can set the title with no problem as you know which fragments was just selected. In the `onActivityCreated` you can set the title by using the `getActivity()` method(and you already have the id at your disposal). *Is there an event that is only fired when the user selects on item and not swipes though?* - I don't know what you understand by selects an item.

Comment: So the user can select an item in the `ListView` by pressing on it, or by swiping.  If I'm only setting the title in `onPageSelected`, then title never gets set if the user manually selects an item.  If I set the title in `onActivityCreated` of the details fragment, then the title is getting set when the `ViewPager` is hitting the details fragment.  It's a little confusing I know, I might make a separate question to illustrate it better.